# Alphabetic Fannkuch

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

[Fannkuch](http://3e8.org/pub/scheme/doc/lisp-pointers/v7i4/p2-anderson.pdf) is a classic benchmark program. The name comes from the German "Pfannkuchen"- pancakes- for the algorithm's resemblance to flipping stacks of pancakes. A Fannkuch sequence of *numbers* is formed as follows:

> Take a permutation of {1.....n}, for example: {4,2,1,5,3}. Take the
>   first element, here 4, and reverse the order of the first 4 elements:
>   {5,1,2,4,3}. Repeat this until the first element is a 1, so flipping
>   won't change anything more: {3,4,2,1,5}, {2,4,3,1,5}, {4,2,3,1,5},
>   {1,3,2,4,5}

You are to write a program or function which calculates a Fannkuch-like sequence for strings of alphabetic characters. Instead of using numbers to indicate how many elements of the list should be flipped each time, the position of a letter in the alphabet should be used. For example, a leading `c` would indicate that you should reverse the order of the first 3 elements, while a leading `a` indicates that the sequence is complete.

### Input

Input will be provided as a string via stdin or as a function argument. The string will contain between 1 and 26 distinct lowercase letters. Strings will not contain letters whose equivalent index would cause the Fannkuch algorithm to flip more elements than exist.

### Output

Programs or functions should return or print to stdout the sequence of terms produced by applying the Fannkuch algorithm until a leading `a` is encountered, including the initial string. For example, if the input is `bca`, you might print:

```
bca
cba
abc
```

Printed results can use any reasonable separator- commas, newlines, etc. Any choice of whitespace is acceptable.

As another example, if your input is `eabdc` you might return:

```
("eabdc"
 "cdbae"
 "bdcae"
 "dbcae"
 "acbde")
```

### Rules and Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)- the shortest program wins. Standard Loopholes are disallowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
.u+_<NJhxGhN>NJz
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.u%2B_%3CNJhxGhN%3ENJz&input=eabdc&debug=0)

The "repeat until it stops changing" feature of Pyth's reduce functions is really handy here. This is used with `.u`, the cumulative reduce function, to output all results. The body of the reduce is as naive as can be, but I couldn't find anything better.

Answer (score 5):

## T-SQL, 213 bytes

Of course being SQL it's really large, but it was interesting to do.
Created as an inline table function using a recursive CTE query.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F(@ CHAR(26))RETURNS TABLE RETURN WITH R AS(SELECT @ S UNION ALL SELECT CAST(STUFF(S,1,ASCII(LEFT(S,1))-96,REVERSE(LEFT(S,ASCII(LEFT(S,1))-96)))AS CHAR(26))FROM R WHERE LEFT(S,1)<>'a')SELECT*FROM R
```

Expanded

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F(@ CHAR(26))
RETURNS TABLE 
RETURN WITH R AS(
    SELECT @ S            -- Initial string as an anchor for the recursion
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CAST(
        STUFF(                                    -- Stuff into 
            S,                                    -- string S
            1,                                    -- from position 1
            ASCII(LEFT(S,1))-96,                  -- to index value of first char
            REVERSE(LEFT(S,ASCII(LEFT(S,1))-96))  -- the reverse of the index first chars
            )
        AS CHAR(26))
    FROM R 
    WHERE LEFT(S,1)<>'a'  -- recurse until first char is a
)SELECT*FROM R
```

Used as follows

```sql
SELECT * FROM F('eabdc')
S
--------------------------
eabdc                     
cdbae                     
bdcae                     
dbcae                     
acbde                     

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 22 bytes

This is an anonymous function which takes a string on stack and returns a list of string on the stack.

```
{_,{_0='`-/(W%\+s_}*]}
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22eabdc%22%7B_%2C%7B_0%3D'%60-%2F(W%25%5C%2Bs_%7D*%5D%7D~ed)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 59 bytes

```
def p(l):
 print l;o=ord(l[0])-97
 if o:p(l[o::-1]+l[o+1:])
```

I guess this is a rather straightforward answer.  Uses recursion and Python's slice syntax.  Call as: `p('eabdc')`.

Answer (score 3):

### SAS, 131 bytes

```
sub a(s$);outargs s;put s;do while(b ne 1);b=rank(char(s,1))-96;substr(s,1,b)=reverse(substr(s,1,b));if b>1 then put s;end;endsub;
```

An FCMP call routine.  Nongolfed below (with an extra check I highly recommend as SAS crashes if an FCMP routine enters an infinite loop).

---

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;
  sub a(s$);
    outargs s;
    put s=;
    do while (b ne 1 and z<1e5);
        b=rank(char(s,1))-96;
        substr(s,1,b) = reverse(substr(s,1,b));
        if b>1 then put s=;
        z+1;
    end;
  endsub;
quit;
```

Comment: Nice work. We don't get much `proc fcmp` around here.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 78 bytes

```
f l@(h:_)|h=='a'=[l]|1<2=l:f(reverse(take d l)++drop d l)where d=fromEnum h-96
```

Usage: `f "eabdc"` -> `["eabdc","cdbae","bdcae","dbcae","acbde"]`.

Comment: consider using `splitAt` -- you can get it down to 71 bytes!

Comment: @MtnViewMark well i seem to have the exact same algorithm, down to 68 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 21 bytes

```
{(|v#x),(v:*x-96)_x}\
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @JohnE and another byte by rearranging an expression.

For the first time on earth, I think K has beaten CJam!

### 27-byte version

```
(~97=*){(|v#x),(v:-96+*x)_x}\
```

Comment: You can make this quite a bit shorter if you use the fixed-point form of "scan".

Comment: @JohnE Thanks! I didn't realize that, when the first letter is an `a`, the string won't change.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 68

```
f l@(x:_)|x<'b'=[l]|(x,y)<-splitAt(fromEnum x-96)l=l:f(reverse x++y)
```

Any more complicated tactic I thought of took more bytes.